# How can I check if my agent is actually in the wait block in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have a model which I am working on, where I need to free some agents from the wait block based on some condition.

```
if(wait1.getAgent(AGENT)==true){
List <Pallet> pallet=findAll(wait1,p->p.ProductType.equals(NutritionPowder)); // create a list of products that belong the same client as the agent that arrived
if(pallet.size()>=OrderSize){ //check if the batch size is reached
//batch.set_batchSize(agent.batchSize);
for(int i=0; i<OrderSize ; i++){
for(Pallet p :pallet){
wait1.free(p);
}
}
}
else create_Create(1,HOUR,OrderSize,AGENT);
traceln("False is dynamic");
traceln(pallet.size() + "Size");
traceln("Order Size is: " + OrderSize);
}
else //do nothing;
```

The first line of the code is wrong, and I need help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
if(agent.currentBlock()!=null && agent.currentBlock().equals(wait1))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can employ this code for monitoring agents lingering in the Wait block, setting them free given specific circumstances, and thus more effectively managing the dynamics of your model.

```
HashSet<Pallet> waitingPallets = new HashSet<>();

waitingPallets.add(agent);

waitingPallets.remove(agent);

void checkAndReleaseAgents() {
if (waitingPallets.size() >= OrderSize) {
    Iterator<Pallet> iterator = waitingPallets.iterator();
    int count = 0;
    while (iterator.hasNext() && count < OrderSize) {
        Pallet pallet = iterator.next();
        waitBlock.free(pallet); 
        iterator.remove();
        count++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Description: The method contains(Pallet) is undefined for the type Wait<Pallet>. Location: Final Model draft 4/Main/Create - Dynamic Event

I tried that also

Comment: To efficiently oversee and handle the Pallet-type agents hanging out in the Wait block, consider leveraging a HashSet<Pallet> collection within your model's prime class for monitoring those awaiting agents. I've updated the code, please try it.